# how do I read a local file in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, input, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, utl-file

I want to read a file on my local machine that contains query parameters when I execute a query in Oracle SQL developer.  The examples that I've found on the web so far are inadequate.  I keep getting "ORA-29283: invalid file operation" errors when I execute the below code:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY SAMPLEDATA2 AS 'C:';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY SAMPLEDATA2 TO PUBLIC;


declare
f utl_file.file_type;
s varchar2(200);
c number := 0;

BEGIN

f := utl_file.fopen('SAMPLEDATA2','sample2.txt','R');
loop
    utl_file.get_line(f,s);
    dbms_output.put_line(s);
    c := c + 1;
end loop;

exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then
        utl_file.fclose(f);
        dbms_output.put_line('Number of lines: ' || c);
end;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTL_FILE.FOPEN() procedure not accepting path for directory ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751113/utl-file-fopen-procedure-not-accepting-path-for-directory)

Answer (score 4):

`UTL_FILE` can only read data from files that are stored on the database server.  Since it is PL/SQL code, it runs on the database server and only has access to the resources that are available to the Oracle process on the database server.

Comment: O.K., that's why that's failing, thanks.  Is there an alternative that I can use to read a local file and send it to the database?

Comment: @user786149 - Not really.  You could do something like use SQL*Loader to write the file to a CLOB column in a table in the database and then use the `DBMS_LOB` package to read the data from the CLOB.  But that would be quite different semantics.  You would generally be better off copying the file to the database server and using `UTL_FILE` to read the file (assuming, of course, that you wouldn't be better off using SQL*Loader to just load the data from the file into a table).

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to read a file on my local
>   machine that contains query parameters
>   when I execute a query in Oracle SQL
>   developer."

This seems an unusual - I was going to say 'peculiar' -architectural decision.  Where do these values comne from?  Why do thay have to be stored in a file?  How often do they change?

It is going to be very difficult to expose the contents of a local PC file to a remote database server (i.e. we're talking automating it with `ftp` or a manual process involving something like WinSCP).

On the other hand, it could be quite simple to apply some query parameters to a query; for instance by using SYS_CONTEXT and namespaces.  But I need to know more details before I can provide an alternative solution.

Comment: It's a one time data migration procedure that involve a dozen different tables and around 1500 distinct dates that are not consecutive.  I have all the information in a flat file so I thought it would be simplest to read that flat file as input to the migration scripts.

Comment: Well, heck, if it's a one-time load, screw elegance and turn your data into a script of a bunch of insert statements and toss it all into a temp table for further massaging later. (I do this in Excel personally.)