# Reading Text Document from PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE file_trial IS
  V1 VARCHAR2(32767);
  F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C:\TEMP','AVI','R',256);
  UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F1,V1,32767);
 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1);
END file_trial;
```

This code while executing gives

> ORA 29280 : INVALID DIRECTORY PATH"

But file (avi.txt) present in temp folder

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTL_FILE.FOPEN() procedure not accepting path for directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751113/utl-file-fopen-procedure-not-accepting-path-for-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a DIRECTORY in Oracle

As SYS:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY MY_SYMBOLIC_NAME AS 'C:\TEMP';
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY oraload TO my_user;
```

You can now open files in the directory using the symbolic name and the file name (including file name extension):

```
F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MY_SYMBOLIC_NAME','AVI.TXT','R',256);
```

Note that a DIRECTORY in Oracle points to a file system directory accessible from the database server as pointed out by  Sathya.

Comment: You should mention this will work only if the directory exists on the database server, not at the client end.