# cat a file value in plsql

Tags: oracle, file, plsql, cat

I am just wondering is there any way that we can print the values of a file in plsql

thing is:

I select 5 columns from a table and one of the column is a path/file.
I want to print the contents of the file

I know its complex but will be good if someone shows me a way.

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to use [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_file.htm) to read the file, and [dbms_output](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_output.htm) to print it.
Note, that you'll have to tell ORACLE which paths can hold the files (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2753582/1083652))

Another way could be to use a java stored procedure, see this [AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve or what the context is. The key words "External Tables" or utl_file Package or CLOB data type might be of interest to you.http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#sthref777