# Get column values from multi-line text file

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I populate the columns with data from a text file, where each line is a different column? The text file looks like this:

```
Amsterdam Aalsmeerweg  
Aalsmeerweg
14
Amsterdam
NL
1059NJ
0204122131

Amsterdam Bos en Lommerweg
Bos en Lommerweg
215
AMSTERDAM
NL
1055DT
0206847676

Amsterdam Ceintuurbaan  
Ceintuurbaan  
314 
AMSTERDAM
NL
1072GL
0204705292
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823382/read-text-file-to-insert-data-into-oracle-sql-table?rq=1) didn't help me.

My code looks like this:

```
set serveroutput on;
 CREATE or replace DIRECTORY USER_DIR AS '/home/renejanssen/'; 
 GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY USER_DIR TO PUBLIC;
 declare
  V1 VARCHAR2(200); 
  F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
  f_name WINKEL.NAAM%type;
  f_adres varchar2(255);
  f_homenr WINKEL.HUISNR%TYPE;
  f_city varchar2(100);
  f_countrcode varchar(255);
  f_zipcode WINKEL.POSTCODE%TYPE;
  f_phonenr WINKEL.TELNR%TYPE;
  v_counter number DEFAULT 1; --counter for ID
 BEGIN
  F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('USER_DIR','test','R');
   Loop
    BEGIN
     UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(F1,V1);
     dbms_output.put_line(v_counter || ' = ' || V1);
     EXCEPTION WHEN No_Data_Found THEN EXIT;
     dbms_output.put_line('niets'); 
    END;                                
   f_name     := substr(V1,1); 
   f_adres     := substr(V1,1);
   f_homenr    := substr(V1,1);                    
   f_countrcode  := substr(V1,1);
   f_zipcode  := substr(V1,1);        
   insert INTO WINKEL (ID, NAAM, HUISNR, POSTCODE, TELNR ) 
   values(v_counter, f_name, f_homenr, f_zipcode, f_phonenr);           
   v_counter := v_counter +1;
 end loop; 
 IF UTL_FILE.IS_OPEN(F1) THEN
 dbms_output.put_line('File is Open');
 end if;                 
 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(F1); 
END;
```

Comment: Are there always 7 lines for each entry? If not are you using a blank line as the delimiter, and how would you map lines in the file variables?

Comment: I dont know, what do you suggest. All i know is that each line needs a variable.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it's your data?

Comment: Nope its a school project.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: If it's a school project, it is probably safe to assume every "record" is seven lines, in the exact same order every time, separated by blank lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each entry in the file always has seven lines as you've shown, followed by a blank line, you can do seven reads directly into your PL/SQL variables:

```
declare
  v1 varchar2(200);
  f1 utl_file.file_type;
  f_name winkel.naam%type;
  f_adres varchar2(255);
  f_homenr winkel.huisnr%type;
  f_city varchar2(100);
  f_countrcode varchar(255);
  f_zipcode winkel.postcode%type;
  f_phonenr winkel.telnr%type;
  v_counter number default 1; --counter for ID
begin
  f1 := utl_file.fopen('D42','test','R');
  loop
    begin
      utl_file.get_line(f1, f_name);
      utl_file.get_line(f1, f_adres);
      utl_file.get_line(f1, f_homenr);
      utl_file.get_line(f1, f_city);
      utl_file.get_line(f1, f_countrcode);
      utl_file.get_line(f1, f_zipcode);
      utl_file.get_line(f1, f_phonenr);
    exception
    when no_data_found then
      exit;
      dbms_output.put_line('niets');
    end;
    insert into winkel(id, naam, huisnr, postcode, telnr)
    values (v_counter, f_name, f_homenr, f_zipcode, f_phonenr);
    v_counter := v_counter +1;
    begin
        -- consume possible blank line; don't error as final entry may not have one
    utl_file.get_line(f1, f_adres);
dbms_output.put_line('extra line: ' || f_adres);
    exception
    when no_data_found then
dbms_output.put_line('extra line: ' || sqlerrm);
      null;
    end;  
  end loop;
  if utl_file.is_open(f1) then
    dbms_output.put_line('File is Open');
  end if;
  utl_file.fclose(f1);
end;
/
```

With your data file that populates a table with:

select * from winkel;

```
        ID NAAM                                     HUISNR     POSTCODE   TELNR        
---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- --------------
         1 Amsterdam Aalsmeerweg                    14         1059NJ     0204122131    
         2 Amsterdam Bos en Lommerweg               215        1055DT     0206847676    
         3 Amsterdam Ceintuurbaan                   314        1072GL     0204705292
```

Comment: Okey Alex, that helps me alot, i can work from there. Thanks!

Comment: @ReneJanssen - if the answer is indeed what you needed, it is customary to mark it as "correct answer" - that way the question will not be on the list of unanswered questions. This will help save time for volunteers on the forum. Cheers!