# Oracle error when writing XML to a file using dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file

Tags: xml, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am running into a scenario like when I am writing a XML file to a folder using PL/SQL it works, whereas when writing using stored procedure it fails and throwing an error as below

```
ORA-29289: directory access denied
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR", line 317
ORA-06512: at "TESTPROC", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

### PL/SQL

```
declare
l_xmldoc clob;
begin
select XMLElement("dateval", sysdate).getClobVal() into l_xmldoc from dual;
dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(l_xmldoc, 'XML_EDI_FILES', 'file1.xml', nls_charset_id('UTF8'));
end;
```

### SP

```
create or replace procedure testproc is
l_xmldoc clob;
begin
select XMLElement("dateval", sysdate).getClobVal() into l_xmldoc from dual;
dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(l_xmldoc, 'XML_EDI_FILES', 'file1.xml', nls_charset_id('UTF8'));
end;
```

I am sure that all the privileges are granted to the directory that I am writing to and that is why it works while using PL/SQL I believe.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The error disappeared after grant of read, write privileges from "sys" user to "user1"

However, my question is that the directory was created from user "user1", so I assume that all the privileges are granted to that directory by default. So why should it throw an exception when executing procedure? when it works with PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question was made sometime ago, but, I think I can help a little.

As @jose mentioned in his answer, that he created the directory on Oracle using the `user1`, although, when you call then `dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file` it uses the `SYS.UTL_FILE` PL/SQL Package internally to save the file on disc.

Take a look if the `user1` has the permission to `execute` the `SYS.UTL_FILE`.

You can find more about `SYS.UTL_FILE` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_file.htm).

There's also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751113/utl-file-fopen-procedure-not-accepting-path-for-directory).