# Copying data from a text file to a CLOB in PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, file, plsql, clob

I have used the following code to copy the text from a file to a CLOB. However it is giving me a PL/SQL numeric or value error at the position where writeappend is performed.

```
    declare
  l_fhandle utl_file.file_type;
  l_clob    CLOB;
  l_buffer  VARCHAR2(4096);
BEGIN
  l_fhandle := utl_file.fopen('/data',
                              'FILE.TXT',
                              'R');
  dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      utl_file.get_line(L_FHANDLE, l_buffer);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_buffer);
     dbms_lob.writeappend(l_clob, length(l_buffer), l_buffer);

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Inside No data found');
        INSERT INTO TAB_CLOB_FILE
          (FILENAME, BODYCONT)
        VALUES
          ('FILE', l_clob);
          dbms_output.put_line('Inserted data into table');
        EXIT;

    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Please help me figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely here:

```
utl_file.fopen('/data', 'FILE.TXT','R');
```

The fist parameter is the name of an oracle directory OBJECT, not a physical path to a directory.  From the Oracle docs, "Directory location of file. This string is a directory object name and is case sensitive. The default is uppercase. Read privileges must be granted on this directory object for the UTL_FILE user to run FOPEN."  The incorrect call should have thrown an exception though.

You need to first create a directory object such as:

```
create directory MY_DIR as '/data';
```

Then change the fopen call to:  `utl_file.fopen('MY_DIR', 'FILE.TXT','R');`

You can read about directory objects [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5007.htm#SQLRF01207).

Comment: Hi, but as given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751113/utl-file-fopen-procedure-not-accepting-path-for-directory, i guess the two methods of opening the file are permitted,opening by providing the directory name as well as physical path and the error is not occuring at fopen. It was occuring at writeappend